# Sencha Touch 2: localstorage creates multiple ids

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

My User has the following config:

```
identifier: 'uuid',
proxy: {
    type: 'localstorage',
    id: 'tm-user'
}
```

But in my localstorage the following is shown:

[image]

Why is the id added to the `tm-user` key everytime I save the user profile?

I only overwrite the user everytime if that helps?

```
                    // create user
                    var user = Tm.model.User.create({
                        id: response[0].id,
                        ...
                    });
                    user.save();
```

EDIT: full model requested:

```
Ext.define('Tm.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        hasMany: { model: 'Tm.model.Exam', name: 'exams', autoLoad: true },

        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'username', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'email', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'nameFirst', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'nameLast', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'syncedAt', type: 'date', defaultValue: null }
        ],

        validations: [
            { field: 'id', type: 'presence' },
            { field: 'username', type: 'presence' },
            { field: 'syncedAt', type: 'presence' },
            { field: 'email', type: 'presence' },
            { field: 'email', type: 'email' },
            { field: 'username', type: 'length', min: 3 }
        ],

        identifier: 'uuid',
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'tm-user'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post full code for your model?

Comment: @sha full model added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following (if you're using UUID type should be string, not int.

```
{ name: 'id', type: 'string' }
```

And change identifier definition like:

```
identifier: {
  type: 'uuid',
  isUnique: true
}
```

**Update**

Since you're receiving Ids from the server and they are not UUIDs you might try the following. Change identifier configuration to this:

```
identifier: {
  type: 'sequential',
  isUnique: true
}
```

and of course type of `id` should be `int` in this case. If that doesn't work however I would recommend still use first approach (using uuid) but store id you're receiving from the server in some different field (`item_number` for example) and let ST handle unique UUID field.

Comment: That didn't solve it. I assume I must explicitly erase it beforehand?

Comment: I'm not sure what the GUID is; it's the id of my data and the model's internalId. Everytime I save it just adds it, instead of updating/overwriting, e.g. `33,33,33,33,33`

Comment: Instead of 33 you should see something like '1234-5678-ABCD....'. You also don't need to specify id when you create a record - it should be assign automatically. Are you receiving it from the server?

Comment: Yes, I wish to use the id from the objects I receive from the server, in order to do `store.findRecord('id', 33)`

Comment: Then you Id ideology must be completely different. They are not uuid. Let me update my answer.